# Laravel websocket and react native - ExceptionsManager.js:180 TypeError: Cannot read property 'presenceChannel' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, laravel-echo, pusher-js, laravel-websockets

I have developed a react app using laravel and react-js by laravel-websockets and it works well!
However, when I want to use it in a **react native application**, It throws an exception:
ExceptionsManager.js:180 TypeError: Cannot read property 'presenceChannel' of undefined
I really appreciate your time and I hope for a solution.

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js/react-native'
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
newEcho() {
        Pusher.logToConsole = true;
        let push = new Pusher('******',{
            wsHost: 'push.******.com',
            wssPort: 6001,
            wsPort:  6001,
        })
        return new Echo({
            broadcaster: push,
            key: '********'
            disableStats: true,
            forceTLS: true,
            authEndpoint: 'https://*******/broadcasting/auth',
            auth: {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${API_TOKEN}`,
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                },
            },
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let EchoChannel = this.newEcho().join(`chat.${this.state.drtoken}`);
        console.log(EchoChannel);
    }
```